# Pagination in Highly dynamic and Frequently change Data in java

Tags: java, android, ios, pagination, restlet

I am java developer and my application is in iOS and android.I have created web service for that and it is in restlet Framework as JDBC as DB connectivity.
My problem is i have three types of data it is called intersection like current + Past + Future.and this intersection contain list of user as a data.There is single web service for giving all users to device as his/her intersection.I have implement pagination but server has to process all of his/her intersections and out of this giving (start-End) data to device.I did this because there are chances that past user may also come in current.This the total logic.
But as intersection grows in his/her profile server has to process all user.so it become slow and this is obvious.also device call this web service in every 5 minutes.
please provide better suggestion to handle this scenario.

**Thanks in advance.
Ketul Rathod**

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to follow your logic, but it sounds like you can probably benefit from caching your results on the server.

If it makes sense, after every time you process the users data on the server, save the results (to a file, to a database table, whatever).  Then, in 5min, if there are no changes, simply return the same.  If there were changes, retrieve from cache (optionally invalidating the cache in the process), append those changes to what is cached, re-save the results in the cache, and return the results.

If this is applicable to your workflow, your server-side processing time will be significantly less.

Comment: When user come in your radius that user consider as a current intersection.(current intersection is like 2 user same time and same location).so when any user come in that radius we have to change the cache result.I do not how frequently we have to change the cache.and refresh the result.